# Punch weapon vs. Swing weapon ,which applies more force to target?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

Have been told the punch weapons i.e. katar impact with more force than a swing weapon i.e. broadsword . My question is simple which applies more force to target with an impacted hit ? Please back up your answer with science and math ,hope to use this in future,will give credit .

Comment: As the impacts have very different impact area, it is hard to evaluate. The swing may have bigger energy to absorb due longer path, but OTOH, it gets better absorbed by target, so higher impact is needed to cause damage. Some extra evaluation is needed for combination of swing and punch, like for war hammers.

Answer (score 0):

Punch has a greater impact.

When we use a punch the opposing force that is generated is perpendicular to your motion and thus you can be  easier to oppose it, to keep moving your hand forward.

$$ F_{hand} = F_{target by punch} $$

Whereas when you are using a swinging motion type of weapon you will probably be holding it near to one end and the then hit on the target with the other.

If you consider the end from where you are holding it to be nearly stationary,you can apply the equation of torque about it.
$\tau= r×F$ so if you see,

The force that would be applied to your weapon by the target which will hit it farther away from the stationary point, can generate larger torque because it is farther away, so to oppose the torque, you need to apply a greater force near the ends from where your holding it. So to keep it in motion ,

$$ \tau_{hand} = \tau_{target by swing} $$

$$ r_{hand}× F_{hand} = r_{target}×F_{target by swing} $$
And as $r_{hand} < r_{target} $,
 $$ F_{hand} > F_{target by swing} $$ 
And as $ F_{hand} = F_{target by punch}$ 
$$F_{target by punch} > F_{target by swing} $$

Hence Prooved.

Considering a person is using the weapon and he can apply the same amount of force in both the cases.